# Angular post html request url

Tags: angular

I send a http post to an oauth2. 
My angular version is 7

My Service code:

```js
const httpParams = new HttpParams()
            .set('username', email)
            .set('password', password);
            console.log('going to send post');
        return this.http.post<any>(oauthservice.com/oauth, httpParams)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

In my component i get my service function

```js
this.authService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data); // Data which is returned by call
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error); // Error if any
      },
      () => {
    });
```

My error message is:

```
error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 24 column 1 of the JSON data"
text: text: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<html>\n<head>\n    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n    <title>WSO2 Identity Server</title>\n    \n    <link rel=\"icon\" href=\"images/favicon.png\" type=\"image/x-icon\"/>\n    <link href=\"libs/bootstrap_3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n    <link href=\"css/Roboto.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
```

The return of my post is a web page, my post is converted to a GET with some headers:

```
Request Url: https://oauthservice.com/oauth?code=98uytghjkl
Request method:GET
```

How can i get a Request Url from make a redirection to this page?

Comment: after successfull login it will redirect to a redirection url with a code.... using the code you have to generate the token

Comment: Because it's an html response and not a json, I always go to error case

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign received data of type any.

```
this.authService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value).subscribe((data:any) => {
        console.log(data); // Data which is returned by call
      },(error:any) => {
        console.log(error); // Error if any
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the response as a JSON object.

Service code:

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';

const options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
});

return this.http.post(url, data, options).pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
        return res.json();
}));
```

Service function:

```
this.authService.login(username, password).subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
}, (err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: The problem is the service that i call change my http post by http get and i need capture this new url and redirect the user to this.

Comment: You use WSO2 right? You need to check the API if you must create a callback function.